# Adding a class to the active li in a menu

Tags: ruby, templates, sinatra, haml

Here's my haml code:

```
%li.active
  %a{ :href => "#" } Home
%li
  %a{ :href => "#" } About
%li
  %a{ :href => "#" } Sign up
%li
  %a{ :href => "#" } Log in
```

What would be the cleanest way of adding the `.active` attribute to the element which represents the current page? I've thought of passing a string to the template and looping through all the elements, building the menu from a hash, but it seems like there has to be a cleaner way.

Is there a 'correct' way of doing this? I have to assume it's a very common operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have too many navigation items, you could do something like this:

```
%li{ :class => @selected == :home ? "active" : nil }
```

Comment: I only have a few nav items so it's clean enough. Thanks!